# How to seed MongoDb with username/password data?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport-local, seeding

I created an app using MongoDB, NodeJS, Express.

I am using [passport-local-mongoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-local-mongoose) for user authentication. Thus my users collection has:
* username
* password
* Salt
* Hash

Basically I created a web app and I'm trying to create 100 fake users just to populate the site (testing purposes).

After some initial research, I decided that creating JSON data then using MongoDB import would be the best approach (what do you think?)

My question is:
-- What is the best way to create a random username, password, salt, hash?

I was looking at this, but it doesn't have Hash https://www.npmjs.com/package/random-user

Then
https://www.npmjs.com/package/password-hash
But I can't get salt...

What would you do?

Answer (score 0):

If it was me ( and I do this all the time just for the sake of testing) I'd go for a for loop :

```
for (var i=0; i <= 100; i++){

// add the user and pwd .you could even use math.random() to randomize your data

}
```

There's also an API called Faker , you can install it with npm . But above was only my quick method of doing things.

Good luck